# magento product flat tables row size too large

Tags: magento-1.9, database, indexing

When I re-index data in magento 1.x with large attribute set about 200 attributes. The got me followin MySQL error.

> Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
>   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may he                                                                     lp. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.' in /var/www/html/uat/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting a max limitation for the number of columns in a database table as described here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/

There's an article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large and here: https://serverfault.com/questions/326836/issue-with-maximum-row-size-in-mysql/326870#326870 regarding this.  It's not a Magento issue per se and needs to be tackled at MySQL application level (or you need to reduce the number of attributes you're storing in the flat table).

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite following class:

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php

add following code inside

> public function prepareFlatTable($storeId)

```
foreach ($columns as $fieldName => $fieldProp) {
    if (!isset($fieldProp['length'])) {
        $columnLength = null;
    } else {
        if ($fieldProp['type'] == 'text' && $fieldProp['length'] == 255) {
            $columnLength = 140;
        } else {
            $columnLength = $fieldProp['length'];
        }
    }

    $columns[$fieldName] = array_merge($columns[$fieldName], ['length' => $columnLength]);
}
```

After

```
if (Mage::helper('core')->useDbCompatibleMode()) {
         /* Convert old format of flat columns to new MMDB format that uses DDL types and definitions */
        foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
            $columns[$key] = Mage::getResourceHelper('core')->convertOldColumnDefinition($column);
        }
    }
```

So your code should look like:

```
// Extract columns we need to have in flat table
$columns = $this->getFlatColumns();
if (Mage::helper('core')->useDbCompatibleMode()) {
     /* Convert old format of flat columns to new MMDB format that uses DDL types and definitions */
    foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
        $columns[$key] = Mage::getResourceHelper('core')->convertOldColumnDefinition($column);
    }
}

foreach ($columns as $fieldName => $fieldProp) {
    if (!isset($fieldProp['length'])) {
        $columnLength = null;
    } else {
        if ($fieldProp['type'] == 'text' && $fieldProp['length'] == 255) {
            $columnLength = 140;
        } else {
            $columnLength = $fieldProp['length'];
        }
    }

    $columns[$fieldName] = array_merge($columns[$fieldName], ['length' => $columnLength]);
}
```

You can reduce column length this way.

Comment: Thanks @sohel Rana but this solution is not working in my case because I have more then 400 columns in my table. I have found solution regarding tuning mysql configuration rather then change in files.