# Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large Reindexing

Tags: magento2, database, reindex, fatal-error

I am facing : **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation**: **1118 Row size too large**. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs, query was: **`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE catalog_product_entity_int_tmp_indexer_value`**

while trying to reindex. I can't update mysql configurations as my site is on shared hosting. Let me know what I am missing or what can do to solve this issue? 
How can I update the table structure and which table I need to change the fields.

Comment: maybe a duplicate of: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270191/magento-product-flat-tables-row-size-too-large

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're hitting a max limitation for the number of columns in a database table as described here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/

There's an article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large and here: https://serverfault.com/questions/326836/issue-with-maximum-row-size-in-mysql/326870#326870 regarding this.  It's not a Magento issue per se and needs to be tackled at MySQL application level (or you need to reduce the number of attributes you're storing in the flat table).

Comment: I am on shared hosting so cannot change the mysql configurations. Can I do something on magento level like deleting some attributes or attribute sets? Will this solve the issue?